# Why min-width:0 doesn't work for my flex elements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've read that `min-width` is `auto` in flexbox for flex-items. That means that `width` of flex-item depends on its content inside (flex-item can't be smaller than the biggest word inside, and of course flex-item can't be smaller than the inner element with fixed width).

That means that I can establish for my flex-item `min-width: 0` and my element will proceed shrink as before, but it doesn't. Why? What did I get wrong?

My code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.second_group_block, .first_group_block {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.first_group_block {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.block {
  min-width: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.block:nth-child(3) {
  margin: 0;
}

.block:nth-child(6) {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first_group_block">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="second_group_block">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**P.S. After some playing with this example, I found that maybe the cause of this behaviour that I decribe before is its flex-direction and the properties that establish main axis and cross axis. You can look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aL25ys10/) for the second example**

Why does it works like this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @kmp I'm trying to shrink my flex-items, but mainly to understand how this min-width works in flexbox

Comment: Based on screen size or by default?

Comment: Your flex containers *can't* shrink if you have fixed width items inside.

Comment: `min-width: 0;` means, that the box will have a width of `at least 0px`. It does not mean that it will shrink automatically to 0 pixel. As The child have a fixed width, the parent needs to be as large as the child. In this case, the box will either have the declared min-width or that of the child what ever value is larger.

Comment: @tacoshy in the flexbox context, min-width:0 means that an element is able to shrink until 0px if there is no enough space in the main axis. The issue here is that we are on the cross axis so it won't apply

Comment: @Paulie_D they can if we apply the correct configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your expectations are correct but you are missing a small thing. The direction of the `.parent` element is a column one so the min-width has no effect on the child element since there is no overflow restriction (nor a shrink effect) on the cross axis. To add such restriction simply use `max-width:100%`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.second_group_block, .first_group_block {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width:100%; /* here */
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.first_group_block {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.block {
  min-width: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.block:nth-child(3) {
  margin: 0;
}

.block:nth-child(6) {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first_group_block">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="second_group_block">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Worth to note that keeping the stretch alignment will also produce the same result:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*align-items: center; removed*/
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.second_group_block, .first_group_block {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
  justify-content:center;
}

.first_group_block {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.block {
  min-width: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.block:nth-child(3) {
  margin: 0;
}

.block:nth-child(6) {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first_group_block">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="second_group_block">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _Worth to note that keeping the stretch alignment will also produce the same result:_ align-items: stretch means that element will try to fill all parent container, consdering main axis. And I can see this by using green border. But why? Why does it impact on shrinking of element?

Comment: Maybe it happens because of the flex-item's ability to "see" its flex container. When there's `align-item: stretch` flex-item cosiders parent's width (I'm talking about the filling of flex container).

Comment: @Eva *stretch* consider the cross axis, not the main one. It simply means that the element need to have the size of the parent on the cross axis (like width:100% in your case and height:100% if it was a row direction). So the element will get stretched whataver the size of the parent and the child will also follow and shrink as needed